# How to ignore a column in SQL updates

Tags: java, mysql, sql, model, prepared-statement

I have a program that looks through a User model and adds values to a prepared update statement if they are not null as follows

```
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET name=?,email=?,pwd=?,avatar=?,sts=?,bio=?,country=? WHERE uuid=?");
    if(this.name != null) pst.setString(1, this.name);
    if(this.email != null) pst.setString(2, this.email);
    if(this.password != null) pst.setString(3, this.password);
    if(this.avatar != null) pst.setString(4, this.avatar);
    if(this.status != null) pst.setString(5, this.status);
    if(this.bio != null) pst.setString(6, this.bio);
    if(this.country != null) pst.setString(7, this.country);
    pst.setString(6, this.id);
```

The problem I am facing is that I can't have an undefined field in the prepared statement. What can I set fields I don't want to change equal to?

Comment: One way would be to construct the statement to only include the columns you want to change. That would always work properly

Comment: Dynamic SQL anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the parameters, even with `NULL` values.  Then change the `update` to:

```
UPDATE users
    SET name = coalesce(?, name),
       email = coalesce(?, email),
       . . .
   WHERE uuid = ?;
```

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . You should be able to pass `NULL` in as a parameter value.  And the OP is specifically asking for this type of functionality.

Comment: @The Impaler this solution works if you set the `?` values to whatever the user model reads, regardless of whether they are null.

Comment: @IsaacKrementsov Yes, just make sure you change your original logic to always set all parameters. Unset parameters can make your code crash.